# aliases in ON statement are unknown column

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm not finding an answer.

In the ON statement below, I can't get the aliases to work. 
Unknown column 'node__field_plant_descriptors.gid' in 'on clause' 
(d_id will give the same error)

```
SELECT descriptors.Entity_id AS d_id,
genus.field_plant_genus_value AS gval,
genus.Entity_id AS gid
FROM table__plant_descriptors AS descriptors
JOIN table__plant_genus AS genus 
ON genus.gid = descriptors.d_id /* HERE */
WHERE (field_1, field_2) 
IN ( (8758, 8109), (8770, 8060),(8773, 7922) ) 
GROUP BY Entity_id 
HAVING count(Entity_id) = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the alias directly by name.

The as creates a column alias and you can't join on a column alias. You can use an alias in the ORDER BY but nowhere else, unless the alias comes from a subquery.

Try Below Query

```
    SELECT
  descriptors.Entity_id AS d_id,
  genus.field_plant_genus_value AS gval,
  genus.Entity_id AS gid
FROM
  table__plant_descriptors AS descriptors
  JOIN table__plant_genus AS genus ON table__plant_genus.gid = table__plant_descriptors.d_id
  /* HERE */
WHERE
  (field_1, field_2) IN ((8758, 8109), (8770, 8060),(8773, 7922))
GROUP BY
  Entity_id
HAVING
  count(Entity_id) = 3
```

Comment: That explains it. I didn't realize. The above query didn't quite work, but removing the alias from all except the SELECT did it. (and fixing ambiguity in GROUP BY and HAVING). Thank you!